# Casting objects in vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector

I know this question has already been asked, but none of the answers that I have as of yet found seem to suffice. I am creating a vector of pointers to a base class and adding all sorts of derived classes to it. Now, the base class has a virtual function that is overridden in all of the derived classes and that is unique to each of them. So, when I go through the vector and retrieve those objects and call the function on that object, I need it to call the right one, but all it will do is call the base class version. I am even trying to cast the individual elements back to their original class when I retrieve them from the vector but they refuse to be cast! e.g.

```
vector<base*> myBase;

DerivedClass *myDerived = static_cast<DerivedClass> myBase[i];
```

This doesn't work, despite the fact that everything I've read suggests that it should. My debugger says that despite all of this, myDerived is still of type base and it's version of my virtual function is being called.

Any ideas?

```
class BankAccount {
public:
BankAccount(string namein, string typein){
    name = namein;
    type = typein;
    balance = 0;
}
virtual string getType();
virtual void printTransactions() = 0;
virtual int withdraw(double amt){
    return getBalance() -amt;
}
};

class SavingsAccount: public BankAccount {
public:
SavingsAccount(string namein, string typein);
void addTransaction(string transType, string name);
virtual int withdraw(double amt);
void printTransactions();
virtual string getType();

private:

};

SavingsAccount::SavingsAccount(string namein, string typein): BankAccount(namein, typein) {

}

int SavingsAccount::withdraw(double amt){
double aBal = getBalance() - amt;
if (aBal > 0){
setBalance(aBal);
}
return getBalance() - amt;

}


class CheckingAccount: public SavingsAccount {
public:
CheckingAccount(string nameIn, string typein): SavingsAccount(nameIn, typein){

}
virtual int withdraw(double amt);
void printTransactions();
string getType(){
    return "Checking";
}

};

int CheckingAccount::withdraw(double amtIn){
double newBal = getBalance() - amtIn;
if (newBal < 500.00 && newBal > 2.49) {
    setBalance(newBal - 2.50);
}
return newBal;
```

}

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
vector<BankAccount*> myAccts;
SavingsAccount *mySav;
CD *myCD;
CheckingAccount *myCheck;

switch (option) {
        case 1: {
            string name;
            string type;
            cout << "Enter name: ";
            cin >> name;
            getline(cin, dump);
            cout << "Enter account type: ";
            cin >> type;
            getline(cin, dump);
            if (type.compare("Checking") == 0) {
                CheckingAccount myCheck1 = CheckingAccount(name, type);
                myAccts.push_back(&myCheck1);

            }
         case 3:{
         for (int x = 0; x < myAccts.size(); x++) {
                if (myAccts[x]->getName() == name && myAccts[x]->getType() == type) {
                    if (type == "Savings") {
                        mySav = static_cast<SavingsAccount*>(myAccts[x]);
                        double y = mySav->withdraw(amt);
                        if (y < 0){
                            cout << "Insufficient funds!";
                            }
                    }
                     if (type == "Checking") {
                        myCheck = myAccts[x]->GetDerived();
                        double y = myCheck->withdraw(amt);
                        if (y < 0){
                            cout << "Insufficient funds!";
                            }
                        if (y < 497.5) {
                            cout << "Withdrawal fee: $ 2.50" << endl;
                        }


                    }

}
```

Checking Account is a child of Savings Account. Sorry.

Comment: DerivedClass *myDerived = static_cast<DerivedClass*> myBase[i];

Comment: Use `dynamic_cast` - better than `static_cast`

Comment: dynamic cast returns Null

Comment: @user3712524 - Then the object is not `DerivedClass` - Please read up on `dynamic_cast`

Comment: Paste your classes base and derived...

Comment: AS mentioned by @radar above your cast should be to the Pointer to DervivedClass. Would be better if you post some code of your base and derived classes - have you declared the virtual functions correctly ?

Comment: Should also read up about `const` and references. i.e. this would be a better signature `BankAccount(const string &namein, const string &typein)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your concept is correct and shouldn't require any casting.  The whole point of virtual functions is that if you're holding a base class pointer or reference and call a virtual function, the most derived version of this function will be called at runtime.

The error I see is this:

```
    if (type.compare("Checking") == 0) {
        CheckingAccount myCheck1 = CheckingAccount(name, type);
        myAccts.push_back(&myCheck1);
```

You are creating a checking account on the stack, then taking it's address and pushing that address into the vector.  At the end of the `if` block `myCheck1` will go out of scope and be destroyed.  Your vector will have an address to a location in the stack and you will have Undefined Behavior.

Instead do:

```
    if (type.compare("Checking") == 0) {
        myAccts.push_back(new CheckingAccount(name, type));
```

And similar for the other types.  Get rid of all of those casts.  In this version you will have to delete all of the items in the vector at the end.  If you use a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BankAccount>>` then the `unique_ptr` will take care of cleaning up your allocated objects.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `new` to create your accounts... you have:

```
if (...)
{
    CheckingAccount myCheck1 = CheckingAccount(name, type);
    myAccts.push_back(&myCheck1);
}
```

...`myCheck1` gets destroyed when leaving that `if` scope, leaving `myAccts` with a pointer to an effectively random location on the stack that has undefined behaviour if accessed.  Change to:

```
if (type == "Checking")
    myAccts.push_back(new CheckingAccount(name, type));
```

You will then need to have matching `delete`s for the `vector` elements.  Googling "C++ new delete tutorial" would be a good idea.  The next stage is to learn how to use smart pointers, for example - `std::shared_pointer` - which remove the burden of remembering to `delete`.

"Case 3" can be corrected/simplified to:

```
         for (int x = 0; x < myAccts.size(); x++)
            if (myAccts[x]->getName() == name && myAccts[x]->getType() == type) {
                double y = myAccts[x]->withdraw(amt); 
                if (y < 0)
                     cout << "Insufficient funds!";
                if (type == "Checking" && y < 497.5)
                        cout << "Withdrawal fee: $ 2.50" << endl;
            }
```

Notice in particular the `double y = myAccts[x]->withdraw(amt);` - the virtual function makes sure the right version is called without you having to do anything type-specific in the calling code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
class base
{
public:

inline DerivedClass *GetDerived() {return (DerivedClass*)this;}

...
};

DerivedClass *myDerived = myBase[i]->GetDerived();
```

Comment: You should use `dynamic_cast` when down casting, as it allows you to check that the object you are casing is indeed a derived type. Otherwise the result of the cast doesn't make too much sense, and it may create a lot of headaches.